# spring-configuration-metadata.json file is not generated in IntelliJ Idea for Kotlin @ConfigurationProperties class

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, gradle, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm trying to generate spring-configuration-metadata.json file for my Spring Boot based project. If I use Java **@ConfigurationProperties** class it is generated correctly and automatically:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("myprops")
public class MyProps {

    private String hello;

    public String getHello() {
        return hello;
    }

    public void setHello(String hello) {
        this.hello = hello;
    }
}
```

But if I use Kotlin class the **spring-configuration-metadata.json** file is not generated (I've tried both **gradle build** and Idea **Rebuild Project**).

```
@ConfigurationProperties("myprops")
class MyProps {
    var hello: String? = null
}
```

AFAIK Kotlin generates the same class with constructor, getters and setters and should act as regular Java bean.

Any ideas why **spring-boot-configuration-processor** doesn't work with Kotlin classes?

Comment: I seem to be having the same problem using groovy

Comment: I have the same problem despite trying all the suggestions. My environment - IntelliJ 2018.1.3 CE, SpringBoot 2.0.1, Kotlin 1.2.41

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. So the solution is to add

```
dependencies {
    ...
    kapt "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
    optional "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
    ...
}
```

to **build.gradle** file, run **gradle compileJava** in command line and turn on annotation processing in IntelliJ Idea settings **Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Annotation processor -> Enable anotation processing**. The rest of configuration remains [the same](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.5.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html#configuration-metadata-annotation-processor)

Also note that without this line

```
optional "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
```

IntelliJ Idea will complain whith

> Cannot resolve configuration property

message in your **application.properties** or **application.yml**

Comment: Can you suggest a solution for the same issue with groovy?

Comment: As Stéphane Nicoll said, currently Spring Boot supports nothing but Java. During work on Kotlin-based project I came to conclusion that it is better to use Java classes for custom properties. Everything else is a hacks and workarounds (at the moment) for compiler, programming language and IDE.

Comment: I got this working fine in kotlin, using spring boot 1.4.0. Without using propdeps or anything on the java side. In my web module, where all the config is used I added 
    kapt "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"and that was it

Comment: `compileOnly` scope in Gradle 4

Answer (score 6):

For those who want to use Maven instead of Gradle, you need to add an `kapt` execution to the kotlin-maven-plugin configuration.

```
<execution>
    <id>kapt</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>kapt</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <sourceDirs>
            <sourceDir>src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
        </sourceDirs>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <annotationProcessorPath>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
            </annotationProcessorPath>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

There is an open issue [KT-18022](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-18022) that prevents this from working if an compiler plugin such as `kotlin-maven-allopen` is declared as dependency.

Comment: The mentioned issue is fixed and I can confirm that the Maven solution works out of the box when using with Kotlin 1.1.4 and Spring Boot 1.5.6.

Comment: This helps, thank you.

you can also remove this:

```
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
```

To get rid of one of the annoying `[WARNING] Duplicate source root: /Users/youruser/project/src/main/kotlin` warning during the compilation.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin has its own compiler. The meta-data is generated by an [annotation processor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html) that is a hook-point in the Java compiler.

I have no idea if such hook-point is available in Kotlin but in any case, Spring Boot does not support anything else than Java at the moment. Maybe [this would help?](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/06/better-annotation-processing-supporting-stubs-in-kapt/)

Comment: This might help too: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#annotation-processing