# Failing to get `ConfigurationProperties` to work correctly

Tags: spring-boot, configuration

In my Kotlin-based Spring Boot application, I would like to use `@ConfigurationProperties` to access some configuration from my `application.yml` file. However, so far the instance does not seem to get initialized with values from the configuration. Here's what I have:

```
@Profile("create-accounts")
@Component
class InitialAccountsCreator {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var accountConfig: AccountsConfiguration
    val logger = loggerFor<InitialAccountsCreator>()

    @PostConstruct
    fun createAccounts() {
        // This will print 0
        logger.warn("CONFIGURED ACCOUNTS: ${accountConfig.keys.size}");
    }
}

@ConfigurationProperties("accounts")
class AccountsConfiguration {
    lateinit var keys: MutableList<Account>
    class Account {
        lateinit var id: String,
        lateinit var name: String
    }
}
```

I've added an annotation to my `Application`:

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties(AccountsConfiguration::class)
```

The configuration looks like this:

```
accounts:
  keys:
    - id: foo
      name: Bar
```

From debugging so far, it seems like Spring is not even trying to insert the values into the instance.

I also already attempted to add the kapt plugin referenced in [Kotlin with Spring Boot 2.0 @ConfigurationProperties not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49316888/kotlin-with-spring-boot-2-0-configurationproperties-not-working):

```
diff --git a/webapp/build.gradle b/webapp/build.gradle
index faef149..6400bed 100644
--- a/webapp/build.gradle
+++ b/webapp/build.gradle
@@ -25,6 +25,7 @@ apply plugin: 'kotlin-spring'
 apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
 apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
 apply plugin: 'idea'
+apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

 sourceSets {
     main {
@@ -105,6 +106,9 @@ dependencies {
         exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
     }

+
+    kapt "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
+    optional "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
 }

 task integrationTest(type: Test) {
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `AccountsConfiguration.class` with a *dot* as the annotation parameter instead of colons `::`?

Comment: It's working now with the colons. If I use a single dot instead, IntelliJ seems to consider it a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lateinit var keys: MutableList<Account>
```

will not work. instead use

```
var keys = mutableListOf<Account>()
```

Comment: Since this is more of a counter question and not a definitive answer I'd suggest leaving this as a comment.

Comment: Yes, `create-accounts` is enabled. And we also already enable the `kotlin-spring` plugin.

Comment: I also initially put the configuration in the wrong `application.yml` file: I put it in `src/main/resources`, whereas the unit tests I was using to test the behavior read configuration from `src/test/resources`.